# имя файла по умолчанию в asksaveasfilename

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

в IDLE python,если второй раз сохранить файл,в строке ввода окна asksaveasfilename по умолчанию будет стоять сохранённое имя этого файла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какой-то параметр в функции asksaveasfilename,в котором можно таким же образом задать имя файла по умолчанию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен параметр `initialfile`.

***Пример:***

```py
import tkinter.filedialog

tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='test.py')
```

[image: Диалоговое окно]

**P.S.:** [остальные параметры](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html#native-load-save-dialogs).